# MSVC: Can't create a std::variant of std::boyer_moore_searcher

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I'm trying to get my code that compiles on Linux to be compatible with Windows. Here is a simplification of my situation (I have a variant of more than one type in the real situation.):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto searcher(const string& s) {
    return boyer_moore_searcher(s.begin(), s.end());
}

int main()
{
    string pattern = "ABC";
    variant<decltype(searcher(""))> v{ searcher(pattern) };
}
```

When I compile with MSVC 2017, I get the following error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(2603): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>>' to 'void *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(2603): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(2601): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>>::boyer_moore_searcher(const std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>> &) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\variant(537): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>>::boyer_moore_searcher(const std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>> &) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]
1>d:\users\narut\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp(12): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(2603): error C2439: 'std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>>::_Data': member could not be initialized
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\functional(2629): note: see declaration of 'std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::hash<char>,std::equal_to<void>>::_Data'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]
```

The same code compiles with the libstdc++ implementation on gcc. I tried libc++ experimental with clang and it also compiles. Is this a MSVC implementation bug or is there no C++ standard that requires `variant` to work with this particular class?

Comment: Looks like MSVC casts variant contents to `(void*)` somewhere in its implementation and boyer_moore_searcher doesn't work well with that.

Comment: Should I file a bug report?

Comment: that would be optimal, yes: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html . It usually doesn't take long to get a response.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: Certainly this couldn't be a bug in MSVC's variant - I blame boyer_moore_searcher until proven otherwise.

Comment: I can't believe my joke "kneejerk defensive" reaction was right: `boyer_moore_searcher`'s copy constructor is broken (https://godbolt.org/g/7c33k5).

Comment: Oh thanks. I already filed a bug but I will add a comment there that it’s due to the copy constructor.